# SAS: Exporting multiple SAS datasets with some editing into multiple csv files

Tags: sas, export-to-csv

I've been using a code with seemingly no problem for a quite a while now, and today it stopped working and in a pretty weird way.

I have several SAS files in a folder and I want to export each of them into a CSV file, while keeping only some columns and if some condition is satisfied.

The file structure is folders called data_(year) and inside are several files called file_(region number)

```
%macro extract_data(year);
libname lib "c:\data_&year.";

%let file_names = 24 27 29;
%let nb_files = 3;

%do i=1 %to &nb_files.;

   %let next_file = %scan(&file_names, &i);

   data file&next_file. (keep = C1 C2);
      set lib.file_&next_file.;
      if C1 = &next_file.;
   run;

   proc export data = file&next_file.
               outfile = "c:\Export\file&year._&next_file."
               dbms = csv
               replace;
%end;
%mend;

%extract_data(2010)
```

Today this stopped working and the error I get is for the FIRST file where I get an "ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order" underlining set. The really weird thing is that it does this only for the first file (ie in the example above 24) and then the other exports seem to go through. I tried with different triplets of file_names and now the one which didn't work before does (ie file_names = 12 24 27 and in this case 24 exported normally and it was 12 that didn't work).

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Show the actual lines from the SAS log that show the error.  Turn on the MPRINT option so the lines of code generated by the macro will be visible in the SAS log.  There is no `12` in your example code. Where did it come from?  Are those really spaces around the digits 12 or are they other invisible characters?

Comment: Sorry, the list of files is longer as in it would be 12 24 27 and so on I just cut it off for the purposes of this post. I don't know much about SAS and the actual runs inside a secured environment so I can't copy paste error code. But the exact message I get is:
set underlined with 180 then the error 180-322 and then ERRORR: File WORK.FILE_24.DATA does not exist

But after that the export of 27 and 29 work normally.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is invisible characters in your macro variable that is leading to invalid dataset names being generated by your macro.

Try retyping the list of values being assigned to FILE_NAMES macro variable to eliminate any strange characters.

Or to debug try looking at the hex code representation of the value by using a data step like:

```
 data _null_;
   string="&file_names";
   put string $hex.;
 run;
```

Spaces should show as hex code `20`.  Digits are the hex code `30` to `39`.  Any other codes like `09`,`0A`,`0D`,`A0` are invisible characters.